# Issue with MKCoordinateRegion Center not updating when user interacts with MapViewRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am currently using a MapViewRepresentable in SwiftUI, which conforms to UIViewRepresentable and uses an MKMapView to display annotations on a map. The MapViewRepresentable takes a Binding for mapRegion, which is initially set to a default value.

However, I noticed that if I interact with the map (e.g., pan, zoom), the mapRegion binding in my ViewModel doesn't get updated automatically. To solve this, I implemented the mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) method in the Coordinator, updating the mapRegion binding with the current map's region. Here's the code I'm using:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.parent.mapRegion = mapView.region
} }
```

This solution works as expected, but I observed that the view seems to update itself multiple times during this process. The annotation animations triggered by the region change occur three times, which gives the impression of multiple state changes.

I would like to know if there is a better approach to keep my mapRegion binding updated without triggering multiple unnecessary view updates. Is there a more efficient and straightforward way to achieve this? Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is the UIViewRepresentable:

```
struct MapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
var places: [Place]
var onTap: (String) -> Void = { _ in }

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.showsCompass = true
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    uiView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
    updateAnnotations(from: uiView)
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

private func updateAnnotations(from mapView: MKMapView) {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: MapViewRepresentable

    init(_ parent: MapViewRepresentable) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let placeAnnotation = annotation as? Place else {
            return nil
        }

        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: placeAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "placeAnnotation")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false
        annotationView.animatesWhenAdded = true
        annotationView.markerTintColor = placeAnnotation.selected ? UIColor(named: "TripBlue") : Color(hex: placeAnnotation.color)?.uiColor
        annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(systemName: placeAnnotation.icon)
        annotationView.glyphTintColor = .white
        return annotationView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if let _ = view.annotation as? Place {
        }
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        guard let placeAnnotation = annotation as? Place else {
            return
        }
        self.parent.onTap(placeAnnotation.id ?? "")
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.parent.mapRegion = mapView.region
        }
        
    }
    
}}
```

This id the use on SwiftUIView

```
 @ObservedObject var exploreMapViewModel: ExploreMapViewModel = ExploreMapViewModel()

@ViewBuilder func generateMap() -> some View {
    MapViewRepresentable(mapRegion: $exploreMapViewModel.mapRegion, places: exploreMapViewModel.annotationList, onTap: { id in
        withAnimation {
            exploreMapViewModel.selectPlace(id: id, zoom: exploreMapViewModel.mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta)
            exploreMapViewModel.scrollTo(id: id)
        }
    })
}
```

This is the declaration in ViewModel

```
 @Published var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 4.676490, longitude: -74.086259), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
```

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mistake in your `UIViewRepresentable`

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}
```

Should be:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}
```

`self` is a value type, the current `UIViewRepresentable` that was just init, and since in SwiftUI our View structs are init over and over again this is immediately out of date. This means that your `self.parent.mapRegion` is setting an old parent instead of the most recently init one. Instead, you can use `updateUIView` to set new closures on the coordinator, e.g.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    context.coordinator.regionChanged = nil // prevent callback loop
    uiView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true) // todo check if this context is animated
    context.coordinator.regionChanged = { newRegion in
        mapRegion = newRegion
    }

    context.coordinator.onTap = onTap
```